# Is there a way to add "three dots" custom contextual NavigationBar menu in react-native Navigator component?

Tags: react-native

The question exactly about [navigator](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html) component. For example [react-native-menu](https://github.com/jaysoo/react-native-menu) functionality but inside of [navigator](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html).

Here is some example of "three dots" custom contextual menu (but not from react-native Navigator component) what I am talking about:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean something like [react-native-popup-menu](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-popup-menu)?

Comment: Yes, something like it, but is it possible to add it into navigation bar and receive events from this menu? Sorry, may be it is a little bit stupid question, I recently familiar with react. Thanks.

Comment: Mmm... I'd say it is totally possible, yes. You just have to pass a callback to the event handlers (if you use popup-menu, it would be the `onSelect` event) and implement your custom logic. Actually, that package has an example that might help you: https://github.com/instea/react-native-popup-menu/blob/master/examples/NavigatorExample.js

Comment: Ok, I'll try. Thank you for kindly provided reply :)